I reinstalled package llamaindex typescript and my document cannot be Indexed
A few days ago I found out that openai released gpt 4o-mini and I wanted to use this model in my project. So I reinstalled llamaindex and was able to get this model working. From the project, it is a chatbot that reads data from a json file that contains the car data that I specified.
const { OpenAI } = require("llamaindex");
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const { Document, VectorStoreIndex, QueryEngineTool, OpenAIAgent, Settings } = require("llamaindex");
const readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
const path = require("path");

const dataPath = "data/old_nissan.json";
const errorLogFolder = "error_log";

async function main() {
    try {
        // Ensure error log directory exists
        await fs.mkdir(errorLogFolder, { recursive: true });

        // Setup OpenAI and callback events
        Settings.llm = new OpenAI({ model: "gpt-4o-mini" });
        Settings.callbackManager.on("llm-tool-call", (event) => {
            console.log("llm-tool-call :", event.detail.payload);
        });
        Settings.callbackManager.on("llm-tool-result", (event) => {
            console.log("llm-tool-result :", event.detail.payload);
        });

        // Read essay content from file
        const essay = await fs.readFile(dataPath, "utf-8");
        const document = new Document({ text: essay, id_: dataPath });

        // Create vector index from the document
        const index = await VectorStoreIndex.fromDocuments([document]);

        // Create query engine tool
        const individual_query_engine_tools = [
            new QueryEngineTool({
                queryEngine: index.asQueryEngine(),
                metadata: {
                    name: "vector_index",
                    description: `Useful when you want to answer questions about information about cars assembled in Thailand. You must specify details of the vehicles named in the list when user ask you.`,
                },
            }),
        ];

        // Initialize OpenAIAgent with tools
        const agent = new OpenAIAgent({
            tools: [...individual_query_engine_tools],
            verbose: true,
        });

        while (true) {
            const userInput = readlineSync.question("Enter your question (type 'exit' to quit): ");
            if (userInput.toLowerCase() === 'exit') {
                console.log("Exiting...");
                break;
            } else if (userInput.toLowerCase() !== '') {
                const response = await agent.chat({
                    message: userInput,
                });
                console.log('------------------------------------------------------');
                console.log("Response : ");
                console.log(response);
                console.log('------------------------------------------------------');
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);

        // Generate a unique filename for the error log
        const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:.]/g, '-');
        const errorLogPath = path.join(errorLogFolder, `error_log_${timestamp}.txt`);

        // Write the error details to the log file
        await fs.writeFile(errorLogPath, `Error: ${error.message}\nStack: ${error.stack}`);
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);

And when I press run, the program gives me a Syntax Error like this.
Error: Expected "http://", "https://", [ \t\n\r], [([{"'`‘], [0-9], [^ \t\n\r!?([}"`)\]}"`0-9@], [^ \t\n\r!?.([})\]}`"0-9@], [a-z0-9], [a-z], or end of input but "}" found.
Stack: SyntaxError: Expected "http://", "https://", [ \t\n\r], [([{"'`‘], [0-9], [^ \t\n\r!?([}"`)\]}"`0-9@], [^ \t\n\r!?.([})\]}`"0-9@], [a-z0-9], [a-z], or end of input but "}" found.
    at peg$buildStructuredError (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:473:24)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1597:23)
    at SentenceTokenizer.tokenize (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1630:31)
    at E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1660:26
    at #getSplitsByFns (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1774:28)
    at #split (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1755:67)
    at Function._splitText (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1737:35)
    at Function.splitTextMetadataAware (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:1722:21)
    at E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:97:33
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Function.parseNodes (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:95:22)
    at Function.getNodesFromDocuments (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:59:56)
    at E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\node-parser\index.cjs:10:25
    at transform (E:\js chat\node_modules\@llamaindex\core\dist\schema\index.cjs:746:20)
    at runTransformations (E:\js chat\node_modules\llamaindex\dist\cjs\ingestion\IngestionPipeline.js:46:27)
    at async VectorStoreIndex.fromDocuments (E:\js chat\node_modules\llamaindex\dist\cjs\indices\vectorStore\index.js:508:22)

When I encountered this issue, I thought maybe my code was not updated and some packages were no longer usable. But when I tried changing the data to a simple json format like this,
{
    "cars": [{
            "make": "Toyota",
            "model": "Corolla",
            "year": 2023,
            "type": "Sedan",
            "engine": "1.8L",
            "assembled_in": "Thailand"
        },
        {
            "make": "Honda",
            "model": "Civic",
            "year": 2023,
            "type": "Sedan",
            "engine": "1.5L Turbo",
            "assembled_in": "Thailand"
        },
        {
            "make": "Mitsubishi",
            "model": "Xpander",
            "year": 2023,
            "type": "SUV",
            "engine": "1.5L",
            "assembled_in": "Thailand"
        },
        {
            "make": "Mazda",
            "model": "CX-5",
            "year": 2023,
            "type": "SUV",
            "engine": "2.5L",
            "assembled_in": "Thailand"
        },
        {
            "make": "Isuzu",
            "model": "D-Max",
            "year": 2023,
            "type": "Truck",
            "engine": "3.0L",
            "assembled_in": "Thailand"
        }
    ]
}

When I run the code with this json data it works fine, but when I change it to my normal data like this
{
    "Car": "Car",
    "year": 2024,
    "active": true,
    "models": [{
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "Almera 1.0L Turbo",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿549,000 - ฿699,000",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "9 color\nblack (black star) ,\ngrey (gun metalic) ,\ngrey (sky pearl) ,\nwhite (strom white) ,\nred (radiant red) ,\nblue (night blue) ,\nblack (black star) with black roof , \nblack (black star) with black roof ,\nblack (black star) with black roof",
                "Body Type": "Sedan",
                "Segment": "eco car",
                "Door": 4,
                "Seat": 4
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "auto",
                "Powered by": "gasoline",
                "Fuel type": "Benzene",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 35,
                "Consumption rate": "23.3 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 1000,
                "Horsepower": 100
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- Dual front SRS airbags\n- Side airbags (Side Airbags)\n- Side Curtain Airbags\n- Anti-lock Braking System (ABS)\n- Electronic Brake Force Distribution System (EBD)\n- Brake Assist (BA) braking system\n- Immobilizer key system\n- Anti-theft alarm\n- Central locking system control button\n- ELR driver seat belt with retracting and automatic two-way tensioning (Double Pre-tensioner with Load Limiter)\n- Front passenger seat belt ELR with pre-tensioner and automatic tension release (Single Pre-tensioner with Load Limiter)\n- 3-point ELR rear seat belts, 3 positions\n- ISOFIX child seat mounting points\n- Child protection system for opening rear doors from inside the vehicle\n- Safety structure system Zone Body Concept\n- Third brake light",
                "Features": "- NISSANCONNECT SERVICES\n-Tire Pressure Monitoring Sensor System (TPMS)\n- High Beam Assist (HBA) automatic high beam on-off system\n- Warning system when the car leaves the lane Lane Departure Warning (LDW)\n- Engine starting system from a remote key (Remote Engine Start)\n- Black synthetic leather seats\n- Black cloth seats decorated with dark blue edges.\n- Side mirrors the same color as the car electrically adjustable\n- Intelligent Key - I-Key\n- Engine start button (Push Start Button)\n- Dual front SRS airbags\n- Side Airbags and Side Curtain Airbags\n- Intelligent Forward Collision Warning (IFWC)\n- Intelligent Emergency Braking (IEB) system\n- Control switch for automatic speed control (Cruise Control)\n- Automatic air conditioning system\n- Side mirrors the same color as the car Electrically adjustable and foldable Automatically when locking the car\n- 15\"\" alloy wheels\n- NISSANCONNECT SERVICES\n- Intelligent Around View Monitor (IAVM)\n- System for detecting and sending warning signals of moving objects and people from cameras around the car, Moving Object Detection (MOD)\n- LED headlights with LED Signature Light and automatic headlight on-off system.\n- Engine starting system from a remote key (Remote Engine Start)\n- Wireless charging device"
            }
        },
        {
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "KICKSe-POWER",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿779900 - ฿939,900",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "12 color \nblack (black star) , \nred (radiant red) , \norange (monarch orange) , \nsilver (brilliant silver) , \nwhite (storm white) , \ngrey (gun meatllic) , \nblue (night blue) , \nred (radiant red) with black roof , \norange (monarch orange) with black roof , \nwhite (storm white) with black roof , \ngrey (gun meatllic) with black roof , \nblue (night blue) with black roof",
                "Body Type": "SUV",
                "Segment": "hybrid (e:HEV)",
                "Door": 5,
                "Seat": 5
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "auto",
                "Powered by": "gasoline , electric",
                "Fuel type": "Benzene",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 41,
                "Consumption rate": "26.3 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 1200,
                "Horsepower": 136
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- Dual front SRS airbags \n- Side airbags (Side Airbags) \n- Side Curtain Airbags \n- Anti-lock Braking System (ABS) \n- Electronic Brake Force Distribution System (EBD) \n- Brake Assist (BA) braking system \n- Immobilizer key system \n- Anti-theft alarm \n- Central locking system control button \n- ELR driver seat belt with retracting and automatic two-way tensioning (Double Pre-tensioner with Load Limiter) \n- Front passenger seat belt ELR with pre-tensioner and automatic tension release (Single Pre-tensioner with Load Limiter) \n- 3-point ELR rear seat belts, 3 positions \n- ISOFIX child seat mounting points \n- Child protection system for opening rear doors from inside the vehicle \n- Safety structure system Zone Body Concept \n- Third brake light",
                "Features": "- 6 airbags (Dual front SRS airbags, side airbags curtain airbag)\n- Sporty leather-wrapped steering wheel decorated with silver material, adjustable in 4 directions.\n- Rear parking distance warning\n- Technology to help warn you when you're tired while driving Driver Attention Alert (DAA)\n- Intelligent Forward Collision Warning (IFCW) technology to warn before collisions.\n- Intelligent Emergency Braking (IEB) technology\n- Automatic headlight on-off system\n- NissanConnect 8-inch touch screen with Apple CarPlay and Android auto connectivity\n- Intelligent Around View Monitor (IAVM) technology that detects and sends warning signals about moving objects. Moving Object Detection (MOD)\n- Intelligent Cruise Control (ICC) technology\n- Intelligent Rear View Mirror (IRVM) technology\n- Technology to detect objects behind the car while reversing, Rear Cross Traffic Alert (RCTA)\n- Technology to warn when the car leaves the Lane Departure Warning (LDW) lane.\n- High Beam Assist (HBA) automatic high beam on-off technology\n- Alloy wheels 17 x 6.5 J, gloss black"
            }
        },
        {
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "TERRA SPORT",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿1,199,000 - ฿1,555,000",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "7 color\nblack (black star) ,\nwhite (white pearl) ,\nred (Coulis Red) ,\ngrey (stealth grey) ,",
                "Body Type": "SUV",
                "Segment": "versatile",
                "Door": 5,
                "Seat": 7
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "auto",
                "Powered by": "gasoline",
                "Fuel type": "Diesel",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 78,
                "Consumption rate": "14.43 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 2300,
                "Horsepower": 190
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- ABS braking system with EBD and BA\n- 6 airbags, front / side / and curtain airbags\n- B-LSD limited slip system\n- Vehicle Dynamic Control (VDC) automatic stability control technology\n- Rear window defogger wire panel\n- Third brake light, LED type\n- 1st row ELR seat belts, 3 points, 2 positions, adjustable. Equipped with an automatic pull-back and tension-relieving system. and a reminder system to fasten seat belts\n- 2nd row ELR seat belts, 3 points, 3 positions\n- 3rd row ELR seat belts, 3 points, 2 positions\n- ISOFIX child seat mounting points\n- Intelligent key system\n- Immobilizer key system with anti-theft alarm\n- Rear view camera\n- 4 rear parking distance warning signs\n- Zone Body safety structure\n- Side impact beams\n- collapsible steering wheel When a frontal collision occurs\n- Automatic fuel valve cut-off system In the case of a car overturning",
                "Features": "- Quad-Eye LED headlights and Daytime lights\n- 8\" touchscreen radio with Nissan Connect to connect to smartphones\n- The design allows the seat to be adjusted in many ways and the seat can be folded with just your fingertips with the Auto Tumble Seat.\n- Smart TFT meter screen displays 7-inch 3D driving information with Off-Road Meter.\n- 360 degree safety technology around the car (IFCW, IEB, LDW, IDA)\n- 2.3 liter twin turbo diesel engine, 190 horsepower, with 7 speed automatic transmission - with manual mode"
            }
        },
        {
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "NAVARA PRO-4X / PRO-2X",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿1,030,000-฿1,160,000",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "4 color\ngrey (stealth grey) ,\nblack (black star) , \nwhite (white pearl) , \nred (burning red)",
                "Body Type": "Pickup",
                "Segment": "versatile",
                "Door": 4,
                "Seat": 5
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "auto",
                "Powered by": "gasoline",
                "Fuel type": "Diesel",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 80,
                "Consumption rate": "14.56 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 2300,
                "Horsepower": 190
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- ABS with EBD and BA\n- Rear Differential Lock\n- Dual front airbag with driver knee airbag driver side\n- Side airbag and Curtain airbag\n- Active Brake Limited Slip (ABLS)\n- Vehicle Dynamic Control (VDC)\n- Traction Control System (TCS)\n- Trailer Stability Assist (TSA)\n- Rear defogger\n- High mount stop lamp (LED Type)\n- Adjustable Front seat belt: ELR 3 points X 2 with pretensioner and load limiter\n- Rear seat seatbelt - ELR 3 points X 3\n- ISOFIX\n- Intelligent Key\n- Immobilizer\n- VSS Alarm\n- Rear view camera\n- Rear Parking Sensor\n- Zone body structure\n- Side impact door beam\n- Crashable steering column\n- Automatic fuel valve cut (When rollover)",
                "Features": "- Interlock front grille in an intense black color, decorated with red & orange Nissan emblem, Quad-eye LED headlamps, and the Daytime Running Light.\n- New 2.3-liter twin-turbo diesel engine of 190 horsepower and the 7-speed automatic transmission. Powerful, quiet, and fuel-saving.\n- INTELLIGENT FORWARD COLLISION WARNING (IFCW), INTELLIGENT EMERGENCY BRAKING (IEB), INTELLIGENT DRIVER ALERTNESS (IDA), and 7 SRS airbags.\n- INTELLIGENT BLIND SPOT INTERVENTION (IBSI), INTELLIGENT LANE INTERVENTION (ILI), and HIGH BEAM ASSIST (HBA).\n- Black sporty interior with the red-threaded Quole Modure seats and the power driver seat adjustable in 8 directions.\n- Interlock front grille in an intense black color, decorated with red & orange Nissan emblem, Quad-eye LED headlamps, and the Daytime Running Light.\n- New Black alloy wheels with the off-road All-terrain tires and fender flares.\n- INTELLIGENT AROUND VIEW MONITOR (IAVM) with 4x4 OFF-ROAD MODE.\n- INTELLIGENT BLIND SPOT INTERVENTION (IBSI), INTELLIGENT LANE INTERVENTION (ILI), and HIGH BEAM ASSIST (HBA).\n- Black sporty interior with the Quole Modure embroidered with PRO-4X emblem seats and the power driver seat adjustable in 8 directions.\n\n"
            }
        },
        {
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "NAVARA CALIBRE",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿765,000-฿934,000",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "7 color\ngrey (stealth grey) ,\nred (burning red) ,\nblack (black star) , \nwhite (white pearl) , \ncopper (forged copper),\ngrey (twilight grey) ,\nsilver (brilliant silver)",
                "Body Type": "Pickup",
                "Segment": "versatile",
                "Door": "2,4",
                "Seat": "2,4"
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "manual",
                "Powered by": "gasoline",
                "Fuel type": "Diesel",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 80,
                "Consumption rate": "15.23 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 2300,
                "Horsepower": 163
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- ABS with EBD and BA\n- Dual front airbag\n- Active Brake Limited Slip (ABLS)\n- Vehicle Dynamic Control (VDC)\n- Traction Control System (TCS)\n- Trailer Stability Assist (TSA)\n- Rear defogger\n- High mount stop lamp (LED Type)\n- Adjustable Front seat belt: ELR 3 points X 2 with pretensioner and load limiter\n- Intelligent Key\n- Immobilizer\n- VSS Alarm\n- Rear view camera\n- Rear Parking Sensor\n- Zone body structure\n- Side impact door beam\n- Crashable steering column\n- Automatic fuel valve cut (When rollover)\n\n",
                "Features": "- Interlock front grille with Quad-eye LED headlamps and the Daytime Running Light\n- New 2.3-liter VGS turbo diesel engine of 163 horsepower. Powerful and fuel-saving\n- INTELLIGENT AROUND VIEW MONITOR (IAVM) with the MOVING OBJECT DETECTION (MOD) system\n- 8\" Touch screen radio display with the NissanConnect technology for smartphones connection\n- VEHICLE DYNAMIC CONTROL (VDC), TRACTION CONTROL SYSTEM (TCS), and the HILL START ASSIST (HSA) system\n- Tri-zone climate control A/C system, including the back passenger's zone\n- Exclusive black accessories: 18\" Black Alloy wheels with the full-car Black Edition graphic pattern to enhance the fierceness like no other\n- New 2.3-liter twin-turbo diesel engine of 190 horsepower with the 7-speed automatic transmission. Powerful, quiet, and fuel-saving.\nFront and side acoustic glass for a quiet cabin\n- INTELLIGENT FORWARD COLLISION WARNING (IFCW), \n- INTELLIGENT EMERGENCY BRAKING (IEB), and INTELLIGENT DRIVER ALERTNESS (IDA) system\n- INTELLIGENT BLIND SPOT INTERVENTION (IBSI), INTELLIGENT LANE INTERVENTION (ILI), and HIGH BEAM ASSIST (HBA)\n- Quole Modure leather seats with 8-direction adjustable power driver seat\n- 18\" Two-tone Alloy wheels"
            }
        },
        {
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "NAVARA KING CAB",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿649,000-฿689,000",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "5 color \nblack (black star) , \ncopper (forged copper) , \nsilver (brilliant silver) , \nwhite (white solid) , \nwhite (white pearl) ,",
                "Body Type": "Pickup",
                "Segment": "versatile",
                "Door": 2,
                "Seat": 2
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "manual",
                "Powered by": "gasoline",
                "Fuel type": "Diesel",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 80,
                "Consumption rate": "14.56 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 2500,
                "Horsepower": 163
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- ABS with EBD and BA\n- Dual Front airbag\n- Laminated Glass\n- Rear defogger\n- High mount stop lamp (LED Type)\n- Adjustable Front seat belt: ELR 3 points X 2 with pretensioner and load limiter\n- Intelligent Key\n- Immobilizer with VSS alarm\n- Rear view camera\n- Zone body structure\n- Side impact door beam\n- Crashable steering column\n- Automatic fuel valve cut (When rollover)",
                "Features": "- 2.5-liter diesel engine with a maximum power of 163 horsepower (HPs) and maximum torque of 403 Newton-meters (Nm)\n- 205 mm. ground clearance with high-floor grade fender flares\n- Black interlock front grille with the tailgate spoiler for a touch of sportiness\n- 7-inch touch screen with NissanConnect that supports smartphone connectivity\n- New interior design with a sporty steering wheel, newly designed seats, and back area A/C\n- Remote control key with the central lock and auto door lock systems\n- 215 mm. ground clearance with 17\" alloy wheels and high-floor grade fender flares\n- Chromium interlock front grille with the automatically adjustable and foldable body-colored side mirrors\n- 8-inch touch screen with NissanConnect that supports smartphone connectivity\n- New interior design with a 3D color display and a sporty steering wheel installed with audio control buttons and cruise control system\n- Push Start, intelligent key and auto halogen headlamps"
            }
        },
        {
            "Brand": "Nissan",
            "Model": "NAVARA SINGLE CAB",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Price": "฿595,000-฿659,000",
            "Style": {
                "Color": "3 color\nwhite (white solid) ,\nsliver (brillaint sliver) ,\ngrey (twilight grey),\n",
                "Body Type": "Pickup",
                "Segment": "versatile",
                "Door": 2,
                "Seat": 2
            },
            "Performance": {
                "Gear": "manual",
                "Powered by": "gasoline",
                "Fuel type": "Diesel",
                "Fuel tank capacity, liters": 80,
                "Consumption rate": "14.56 kilometers/liter",
                "Cylinder volume, cc": 2500,
                "Horsepower": 163
            },
            "Feature": {
                "Safety System": "- ABS with EBD and BA\n- Dual Front airbag\n- Laminated Glass\n- Rear defogger\n- High mount stop lamp (LED Type)\n- Adjustable Front seat belt: ELR 3 points X 2 with pretensioner and load limiter\n- Intelligent Key\n- Immobilizer with VSS alarm\n- Rear view camera\n- Zone body structure\n- Side impact door beam\n- Crashable steering column\n- Automatic fuel valve cut (When rollover)",
                "Features": "- 2.5-liter diesel engine with a maximum power of 163 horsepower (HPs) and 403 Newton-meters (Nm) of torque.\n- Mono-Frame Chassis made from one single steel structure.\n- Side step for easier access to your truck bed.\n- Designed to carry cargo and lots of it; capable to fit 14 baskets or 14 boxes per layer and up to 40 pieces when carrying 3 layers with a total weight of 1,090 kg. Note: Box with dimension 35 cm x 50 cm x 32 cm. Baskets with dimension 37.2 cm x 57 cm x 30.3 cm.\n- 7-inch touch screen with NissanConnect that supports smartphone connectivity.\n- Speed sensing auto door lock.\n- Choose full-time 2WD for maximum efficiency or shift to 4WD at speeds up to 100 km/h. Select low range 4WD (4LO) for mud, sandy, or difficult terrain.\n\n\n\n\n\n"
            }
        }
    ]
}

When I run my code it doesn't work. I tried deleting the data to just two cars, it doesn't work. But when I delete the very long data on the line, it works. And when I try to add the other cars back without the long data on the line, it doesn't work. If anyone can answer my question, thank you very much. I'm not very good at coding and am just learning. Thank you so much for reading this question, and thank you very much if you answer!

LLM's tend to have problems interpreting and outputting JSONs if they're simply provided as is, at least for the time being. Based on where your error is occurring it seems the LLM is struggling with the JSON format, it probably doesn't quite understand some of the data in those long lines
When it comes to querying JSON documents you'll have a better time using llamaindex's JSON Query Engine. Essentially, this allows you to define a schema for your JSON file that the LLM can then understand. In your case, the skeleton for your schema would be something like this:
const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    Car: {
      type: 'string',
    }, 
    year: {
      type: 'number',
    }
    active: {
      type: 'boolean',
    },
    models: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

You can then call your LLM using the following code:
const jqe = new JSONQueryEngine({
  jsonValue: essay,
  jsonSchema: schema,
});

const answer = jqe.query({ query: 'your question' });

